# iphone app crashing when I'm using an NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Got this code in my controllers (void)viewDidLoad method

```
self.purchasesPerClassification = [NSMutableDictionary 
                                  dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Moo",nil] 
                                  forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MooKey",nil]
                                  ];
```

as far I can under stand these are auto release as I have not used alloc init,
and in my dealloc i have

```
[self.purchasesPerClassification release];
```

this is part of a controller with UITableViewController and this controller is created an loaded from a main container and added to the main contollers navigationController this seems to make my app crash in the simulator as when I dont have it in the code it works fine any pointers on why this is crashing

heres the .h

```
@interface FirstAiderInsurancePurchasesViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSArray * availableClassifications;

    NSMutableDictionary * purchasesPerClassification;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray * availableClassifications;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * purchasesPerClassification;

@end
```

and heres the .m parts

```
@implementation FirstAiderInsurancePurchasesViewController
@synthesize availableClassifications;
@synthesize purchasesPerClassification;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.availableClassifications = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Completed",@"Recover's",nil];

    self.purchasesPerClassification = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object",nil]
                                                                          forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ObjectKey",nil]];

}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    self.availableClassifications = nil;
    self.purchasesPerClassification = nil;
}
```

I've tried both

```
[purchasesPerClassification release];
```

as well and its crashing when I go back to the root controller

Comment: Ok my bad should have posted the entire source so here's the .h

Comment: just a quick comment.. You will want to do [super dealloc] last.  Probably won't help this problem but could lead to leaks later.

Comment: seems to have fixed it, i had place the release the viewDidUnload method that fixed it as well but called [super dealloc] after the other releases worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what is the property definition of `purchasesPerClassification`?

Anyway, assuming it's copy or retain, you probably want either:

```
self.purchasesPerClassification = nil;
```

or

```
[purchasesPerClassification release];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[NSMutableDictionary    dictionaryWithObjects]` return an autoreleased instance
you have not to `[self.purchasesPerClassification release];`

but [purchasesPerClassification release]

Comment: The autoreleased variable is then assigned to a property that is (probably) retained or copied.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington definitively